# php artisan: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, laravel

I just started to learn php/laravel by following some guides and tutorials, which led me to run a server using `php artisan serve` command.

The steps I took are as follows:

1. install laravel using composer and adding it to `$PATH`.
2. creating a project by using `laravel new new-blog`
3. changing directory into the project foler and running `php artisan serve` command.

However, instead of the expected output of a php server with an address I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/sflash/Documents/php/laravel/new-blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sflash/Documents/php/laravel/new-blog/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/sflash/Documents/php/laravel/new-blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/sflash/Documents/php/laravel/new-blog/artisan on line 18
```

I am on a linux machine (debian buster). The structure of my project folder is like below:

```
app        composer.json  package.json  README.md  server.php  webpack.mix.js
artisan    config         phpunit.xml   resources  storage
bootstrap  database       public        routes     tests
```

As the error code above states, I don't have a file called `vendor/autoload.php`. How does this occur/how to fix this?

Comment: there is no vendor folder in the app directory you have sent, try using `composer update`

Comment: I am getting an error from composer. `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`. with a problem1: `  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[dev-master, 9.3.0, ..., 9.4.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - phpunit/phpunit 9.5.x-dev is an alias of phpunit/phpunit dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.3.0, ..., 9.5.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].` The rest is too verbose

Comment: for ext-dom install php-xml, `sudo apt-get install php-xml` you can even put your php version `sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml`, then restart apache

Comment: I fixed the above error with `phpunit` package. and ran the command. It worked! post it as an answer, I'll vote it.

Answer (score 25):

You have done everything correctly except you forget to add the vendor folder into your project directory,
just try

```
 composer i
```

Inside the project directory from the terminal, will solve your error. And if you get any other error then remove the composer.lock file and then try again.

UPDATE:

Instead of deleting the composer.lock file when facing issues like PHP version mismatch or dependency version locked just use

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 6):

This is caused because you're missing your "Vendor" directory which is causing a missing dependency error. To fix this you need to run:

```
Composer update
```

In most cases, updating the Composer will regenerate the vendor folder and the autoload.php file.

Alternatively, you can regenerate the autoload.php file using the command,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If the Composer is found corrupted, uninstall the existing one and reinstall it. To install Composer, run this command in the root project folder:

```
Composer install
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add vendors directory first by running the install command for the composer:

```
composer install
```

After that update your composer packs:

```
composer update
```

At the end run your migration command

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 2):

All those solutions work if the dependencies have been downloaded.

I ran to a similar issue but with the Composer Update and/or composer i CLI solutions didn't work because there were files/dependencies missing or unable to be located.

I figured out that I required laravel in my project like so : `composer global require laravel/installer` and so the above solutions wouldn't be able to work. So I ran

```
composer help
```

and it led me to use the

```
composer u
```

and it downloaded all the required dependencies necessary.

then the

```
php artisan serve
```

command worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have  vendor folder in you project
you need to re-install laravel & then try install it using

`laravel new project` or `composer create-project ---prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

Comment: As my previous comment above, it appears to give the same error if I use `create-project ---prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`. I think my installation is missing dependencies. such as phpunit. Is there a way to get them all fast?

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem arise when you try to clone a project from GitHub? if true, then make sure the laravel installation on your device is correct by creating a local laravel project first. if the local project runs well, then you can proceed with cloning the project from the repository.
after cloning project, duplicate file .envy.example and rename one of them to .envy then run `composer update` after that `php artisan key:generate` then you can try `php artisan serve` again.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by not (manually) updating section "files" in `composer.json`, i.e.:

```
"files": ["app/Some/Stucked/Refactored/Old/Location.php",
          "app/Some/Good/Location.php"],
```

Then:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and the solution was straightforward.
For Windows operating system, if you are using a local development environment like XAMPP, all you need to do is locate the php.ini file (in my case, it was in `C:\xampp\php`), open it, and remove the semicolon `;` from the following line:

You will find it like this

```
;extension=zip
```

Remove semicolon:

```
extension=zip
```

And it should work properly.